# Function argument contains complete function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

In My C++ library code I saw following line

```
 m_libs[ library_name ] = lib_ptr_t( handle, [](void*d){ dlclose(d); });
```

lib_prt_t declare in .hpp as

```
using lib_ptr_t = std::unique_ptr<void,std::function<void(void*)>>;
```

Can anyone explain , isthere in second argument is a complete function or some thing else.
I can't understand what does it mean?

Comment: "isthere in second argument is a complete function" Yes, it's called lambda expression.

Comment: It's a lamda that's passed to the `lib_ptr_t` as a custom deleter.

Comment: Is c++0x, supports lamda expression?

Comment: @user3906620 [Lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) are C++11+ feature.

Comment: Sometimes. C++0x means "do your best to be C++11 compatible, even though you can't because C++11 doesn't exist yet". Depending on from when the compiler is it may or may not support lambdas.

Comment: Thanks for comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[](void*d){ dlclose(d); }` is a lambda expression.

It is shorthand to create an instance of a class very roughly like this:

```
struct anonymous_name {
  void operator()(void* d) { dlclose(d); }
};
```

(there are some minor differences I skipped that don't matter here).  `anonymous_name` isn't the real name of the class generated, instead it is given a name that cannot be named.

An instance of `anonymous_name` can be called like a function.

Now, `std::function<void(void*)>` is an object that uses a technique called "type erasure" to store *almost anything* that can be called with the signature `void(void*)`.  This includes function pointers, or function objects like instances of `anonymous_name`.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument is the deleter function object for the `std::unique_ptr` and in this case it's a lambda but it could be anything implicitly convertible to `std::function<void(void*)>` which is declared to be the type of the deleter object.